# calculate similarity between one given word and a RANDOM list of words

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, similarity, word-embedding

I want to calculate the similarity between a given one word and a RANDOM list of words, then would rank the result in a new list, for example:

```
list = ['bark','black','cat','bite','human','book'] #it could be another list
```

is similar to the word:

```
word = ['dog']
```

--

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')


bark = nlp("bark")
bite = nlp("bite")
human = nlp("human")
book = nlp("book")
cat = nlp("cat")
black = nlp("black")

print("dog - bark", dog.similarity(bark)) #0.4258176903285793
print("dog - bite", dog.similarity(bite)) #0.4781574605069981
print("dog - human", dog.similarity(human)) #0.35814872466230835
print("dog - book", dog.similarity(book)) #0.22838638167627964
print("dog - cat", dog.similarity(cat)) #0.8016854705531046
print("dog - black", dog.similarity(black)) #0.30601667459001575
```

So how I can calculate the similarity of every word in the list to the given word automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

words = ['bark','black','cat','bite','human','book']
word = 'dog'
word_nlp = nlp(word)

new_words = [(w, word_nlp.similarity(nlp(w))) for w in words]
new_words.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for w, value in new_words:
    print(f"{word} - {w}", value)
```